# How do I structure this SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables and I need to make a certain select.

First table is **Employe** that has colums *Name* *Departament_ID* and *Salary*
The second table is **Departament** that has colums *Departament ID* and *Departament_Name*

My SQL script has to get me the *name of the departament*, *the maximum salay* and *minimum salary* where Departament_ID is '30'

Comment: What did you try ? They are basic queries...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick (note: all spellings are exactly as you gave in your first post).

```
   SELECT d.Department_Name AS name,
          MAX(e.salary) AS max_salary,
          MIN(e.salary) AS min_salary
     FROM Department d
LEFT JOIN Employe e ON d.Department_ID = e.Department_ID
    WHERE d.Department_ID = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.department_name,
       MIN(e.salary) AS 'Minimum Salary',
       MAX(e.salary) AS 'Maximum Salary'
FROM department d,employee e
WHERE d.department_id=30 AND d.department_id=e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
```

Comment: Messy join :P Much more obvious to explicitly `JOIN` when you're doing so, rather than hiding it in the `FROM` and `WHERE` :)

Comment: Sure, but a left join is an overkill here ;)

Comment: Lol, it depends on how you want to handle departments with no employees, and if you use an explicit `JOIN` you can change that by just changing `LEFT` to `INNER`, and it's done for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  max(sal) as MaximumSalary
       ,min(sal)  as MinimumSalary
       ,department.Departament_Name
       ,employee.Name
FROM    employee
INNER JOIN department ON
            employee.departmentid = department.department_id
WHERE department.department_id = 31
GROUP BY department.department_id
```

max and min function will give you the maximum and minimum value of the employee table for the salary column. This will require you to use GROUP BY because they need to calculate the maximum and minimum from a group of data witch in this case is the maximum/minimum by department. We group by department id because it's a unique key of the table. The inner join is here to join the two tables you have. It's an inner join because we want to have the department into the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT d.Department_Name AS name,
      MAX(e.salary) AS max_salary,
      MIN(e.salary) AS min_salary
   FROM Department d
   Inner JOIN Employee ON d.Department_ID = e.Department_ID
   WHERE d.Department_ID = 30
```